# How to perform a complex query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I want to perform a query on this schema:

```
{ 
   "name" : "xxx",
   "guests" : [ 
       {
            "category" : "category 1",
            "arrived" : false
       },
       {
            "category" : "category 2",
            "arrived" : false
       },
       {
            "category" : "category 1",
            "arrived" : true
       },
       {
            "category" : "category 2",
            "arrived" : true
       }
   ]
}
```

I want to get for a certain name, a list with the percentage of guests arrived for each category.

For the document above as example, I want to receive:

```
{
    name : "xxx",
    results : [
         {
              category : "category 1",
              arrived : 50 (percent)
         },
         {
              category : "category 2",
              arrived : 50 (percent)
         },
    ]
```

Is there a way to do this with a single MongoDB query? Also, should I do this computation in the client-side or server-side?

Comment: Addressing where you should do the computation, in general, complex computations should be done on the client side as MongoDB is supposed to be a big, dumb data store which does almost no processing. It just stores and retrieves data. You should respect this goal and try to avoid forcing MongoDB to do any computation that could be done on the client unless if your are willing in incur heavy performance penalties. Even "trivial" tasks, such as finding averages or summing fields should generally be pushed to the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can using aggregate.  Here's an example:

```
[
    {
        $match: {name:"xxx"}
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$guests"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id:"$guests.category",
            guests_arrived: {
                $sum: { $cond: [ {$eq:["$guests.arrived",true]}, 1, 0 ] }
            },
            guests_total: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id: false,
            category: "$_id",
            guests_arrived:true,
            guests_total:true,
            "percent": {
                $multiply: [
                    100,
                    {$divide: ["$guests_arrived","$guests_total"]}
                ]

            }
        }
    }
]
```

Explanation of the aggregation pipeline stages used:

**$match** the on **name**, since you want results only for a specific **name**

**$unwind** the **guests** array so that we can perform aggregate functions on its members in the next stage

**$group** by **category** in order to **$sum** total guests and the number of guests who have arrived
    **$cond/$eq** is used to evaluate **arrived** and only add to **guests_arrived** if arrived=true

**$project** with the primary purpose of computing the percentage based on the aggregate values, **guests_arrived** and **guests_total**, from the previous stage

Comment: thank you it did work! 
can you explain what you did to make it work?